# Play Scala Anorm parser throws UnexpectedNullableFound even when the parser is marked as optional

Tags: sql, scala, playframework, anorm

The table is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Session (
    id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    something varchar(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And my query looks like this:

```
SQL("SELECT something FROM Session WHERE id={id}").on("id" -> id).as(str("something") ?)
```

While this gives the correct type (`Option[String]`) at compile-time it causes a `RuntimeException(UnexpectedNullableFound(SESSION.SOMETHING))` at runtime.

For the record, I'm using Play 1.2.4, Play Scala 0.9.1 and the bundled H2 database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that `str("something") ?` means get from the not-nullable column "something" but I'm not sure if there will be a row or not. I think what you want is:

```
SQL("SELECT something FROM Session WHERE id={id}").on("id" -> id).as(get[Option[String]]("something") ?).getOrElse(None)
```

The SQL statement as is gives us an `Option[Option[String]]`, because we're not sure if the row exists, and if the row is there, we're not sure if the column is null or not. That's why we need to do a getOrElse to just reduce it to an `Option[String]`